# Why are CSS styles displayed by Firebug so different to what I'm seeing in the CSS file?

Tags: css, firebug

I'm trying to make some CSS changes to a website.
When I inspect the elements with Firebug, I find a class `bordered` that I need to make some changes to for example. Firebug tells me this class is in a file called Desktop.css. These are the style rules that Firebug displays for class `bordered`:

```
.bordered {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color #d9d9d9 #d9d9d9;
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: none solid solid;
    border-width: medium 1px 1px;
}
```

But when I look in the actual Desktop.css file, the style rules I see for class `bordered` are:

```
.bordered {
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I must be doing something stupid! Why might I be seeing such differences in Firebug and in the actual CSS file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebug will parse your CSS rules into their full form.

A good example with less clutter is the `background` property.

`background` is actually a shorthand method of writing

```
background-color
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position
```

So if we write `background: #f00;` we'll get a red background, and all the other properties for background will be set to their defaults.

Firebug will show the full value including defaults, which in this case would be:

```
background: #ff0000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
```

Comment: The reason **why** shorthand properties set their corresponding longhand property values to their initial values is that it's defined that way in the [CSS Cascading and Inheritance specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-4/#shorthand-property).